# Upgrade 11.10 to 12.04 on Eee PC failed. GLIBC_2.14 not found

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, eeepc

I was upgrading my Eee PC from 11.10 to 12.04 as prompted and the upgrade locked up (the lappy was plugged into power - so that wasn't the problem). The system won't boot now and I'm getting an error that "GLIBC_2.14 not found". I am unable to boot into any recovery mode or prior version. The lappy was a dual boot, but when I installed Ubuntu the first time, I opted out of that option (whoops). Now I can't load, it goes into a forever 'ubuntu' loading screen. I have a fresh install on a memory stick, but when I set the lappy to boot from it - it doesn't work. Help. I have no idea what to do next...  ??

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue trying to upgrade Linux Mint 12 (Lisa - based on Ubuntu 11.10)to Linux mint 13 (Maya - based on Ubuntu 12.04).

I think you need to install GLIBC manually. If some dependancy issue doesn't let you install it then you might need to remove the offending package, download .deb from one of the repositories, install them manually using 'dpkg' and then try the upgrade again.

Here is a link that I think might be useful:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=103237#p586961